# How do I force a driver for an unknown device from the command line?

Tags: windows-server-core

I have a Mac Pro on which I want to install Server Core (2012 R2 or 2016). The problem is that the Ethernet drivers need to be forced.

On a GUI System, I'd open device manager, select "Update Driver", "Browse my computer", "Let me pick" and then choose the Intel 82574L network adapter, and everything works fine.

Can I do this from the command line? I've seen a bunch of results about using pnputil to add the driver to the driver store, but that doesn't seem to apply - the driver is already part of windows (E1Q62x64.inf on Windows 2016), it just doesn't get automatically detected even though the device id matches (0x8060 Vendor, 0x10F6 Device).

Here's the steps I do on a GUI:

1. Device Manager, Other devices, Ethernet controller, Update Driver
   [image]
2. Browse my computer, Let me pick, select "Network adapters"
   [image]
3. Select the Intel 82574L Network card
   [image]

Comment: You have a Mac without a GUI?